# .htaccess RewriteRule to get pretty links 4

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry, maybe for stupid question, but I really have no idea how to make the following...

For example I have this link:

```
http://www.mypage.com/?section=orders&action=add_order
```

And I want to make it like this (hidding the GET param key, and separate params by slash "/"):

```
http://www.mypage.com/orders/add_order
```

Comment: This would be achieved by RewriteRule in mod-rewrite, and it is a well-known use case.  Attempt it, and if you find problems with the rewrite rule, then someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though kind of ugly and doesn't support infinite number of parameters it works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6
```

If you can write some code you can make a perl script (or any other language) redirect the user after splitting his URI parameters

Comment: BTW: The above code will not redirect the user from "?param1=value1" to "/param1/value1/" it will make both options work

Comment: Its almost worked, but now I have problem with loading .js and .css files.

Comment: Obviously, because /js/myjs.js will be treated as /?js=myjs.js so you need to either exclude a certain directory from being processed as parameters, or a certain extension, i.e. if it ends with `.js`, or `.css` it will not be treated as a parameter

Comment: How I can exclude .js and .ccs file from params?

Comment: Do you know how to use RewriteRule ? i suggest you start by trying to do some work by yourself, by reading RewriteRule. If you fail to, open a new question with what you tried and what you would like it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?section=$1&action=$2 [L]
```